# Understanding the Product of $\Delta$-sets: $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

We learnt that a $\Delta$-set is said to be a sequence $K_\bullet$ of sets

$\{K_n\}_{n\ge0}$ with defined "face" maps $d_i:K_{n+1}\rightarrow K_n$ for $0\le i\le n$ satisfying $d_id_j=d_{j-1}d_i$ whenever $i<j$.

Set $\boldsymbol\Delta^n:=\{(t_0,...t_n):\sum_{i=0}^nt_i=1\}$

We denote by $|K_\bullet|_\Delta$ the geometric ($\Delta$) realisation of $|K_\bullet|$. This is defined by
$$|K_\bullet|_\Delta:=\bigsqcup_{n\ge0}K_n\times\boldsymbol\Delta^n/\sim$$
where $(d_i(x),t)\sim(x,\delta^i(t))$ for $x\in K_n,t=(t_0,...,t_{n-1})\in\boldsymbol\Delta_{n-1},0\le i\le n$.

Here we have$$\delta^i:\boldsymbol\Delta^n\rightarrow\boldsymbol\Delta^{n+1}:=(t_0,...,t_n)\mapsto(t_0,...,t_{i-1},0,t_i,...,t_n)$$

I presume the delta set $K_\bullet\times K_\bullet$ is defined as the sequence $\{K_n\times L_n\}$ with the "face" maps being $d_i\times d_i$: I searched the literature available to me, that I thought could help me confirm/refute this, the wiki page on Delta-sets and Friedman's *An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets* to name some. The latter confirmed this in simplicial case with even the degeneracy maps being defined as $s_i\times s_i$ (for the purposes of this question, no need to know what $s_i$ is).

My first question: Is this indeed the accepted definition for the product of $\Delta$-sets?

Now set $K=\Delta^1$, that is, $K_0=\{0,1\}$, $K_1=\{[0,1]\}$ and $K_n=\emptyset$ when $n>1$. The face maps are $d_0([0,1])=1$ and $d_1([0,1])=0$.

However, I get a fishy result:
$|K_\bullet\times K_\bullet|_\Delta\cong I\sqcup*\sqcup*$ where $I$ is the compact interval and $*$ is a point.

My second question: Is this true?

Pardon the undesirably lengthy question, but just elucidating my efforts at this one.

Comment: Thankful to anyone who checks my answer and comments and/or votes on it.

Comment: The tag "combinatorial topology" is new to the site, and I am trying to figure out whether it fills a useful role. Does [(simplicial-stuff)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicial-stuff) seem to you to be an appropriate tag for these questions?

Comment: Simplicial sets are simply functors $\Delta^{op} \rightarrow \text{Set}$ and it is a general theorem of category theory that the limit of functors may be computed objectwise. Concretely what this means is that if you have some morphism $f$ in $\Delta^{op}$ and two simplicial sets $X$ and $Y$ we have $(X \times Y)(f) = X(f) \times Y(f)$. So yes, the face maps are all of the form $d^X_i \times d^Y_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to First Question: Yes

Answer to Second Question: I checked it using the definition of product of delta-sets analogous to the one for simplicial sets. Here's my best attempt at understanding $K_\bullet\times K_\bullet$, and it yielded the answer $I\sqcup*\sqcup*$ above.

$$K_0\times K_0=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$$
$$K_1\times K_1=\{[0,1]\times[0,1]\}$$

So $|K_\bullet|_\Delta$ is a quotient of 4 $0$-simplices and a $1$-simplex. Since $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ don't occur as images under either $d_0\times d_0$ or $d_1\times d_1$ we see that they remain inequivalent to any other point at all. However $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ get identified with either boundary point of the lone $1$-simplex.